# I need to instantiate a class in Ionic2 angular2 with Type script to make an Http request

Tags: angular, ionic2

I created a basic ionic2 tabbed project
Added the following code with the hopes of calling an Http service.

I get this error on line 57 when I try to create an Http object and pass it into the constructor. 
var atest = new MyTestA(new Http());

app.component.ts, line: 57
Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

L56: atest.getTest();

This is the code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar, Splashscreen } from 'ionic-native';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';
import { MyTest } from '../pages/tabs/mytestfile';

import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})


export class MyApp {
  rootPage = TabsPage;

  constructor(platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.

      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();

    });
  }

}

class MyTestA {

    constructor(public http: Http) { 

    }

  getContent(url, token)
  {
      var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('X-ZUMO-AUTH', token);

        var response = this.http.get(url, {headers: headers}).map(res => res.json());
        console.log("response: " + response);
        return response;
  }

  getTest()
  {
       console.log("test == Works: ");
  }

}

console.log("creating a new Class")
var atest = new MyTestA(new Http());
atest.getTest();
```

Comment: You need to read about angular, services, dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot instantiate the Http like
new Http();
it have too much dependencies. You can go for a service to use http and inject service it into components or direct inject Http. In your components inject your service in constructor. (I'll prefer dont put both classes in same file components should have only one class create service in separate file and inject it using @Injectable().

https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/17/resolve-service-dependencies-in-angular-2.html

```
 export class MyApp {   
  rootPage = TabsPage;

   constructor(platform: Platform, private service: MyTestA) {
    service.getTest(); // notice here
    platform.ready().then(() => {
     StatusBar.styleDefault();
     Splashscreen.hide();
    });
   }
}
```

I injected the class as a service and called method inside constructor